# SQL Descending ordered LEFT JOIN subquery issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following query.

```
SELECT r1.*, 
       r2.vlag54, 
       r2.vlag55 
FROM   [rxmon].[dbo].[a] AS r1 
       LEFT JOIN [rxmon].[dbo].[b] AS r2 
              ON r2.artikelnummer = r1.drug_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM   [rxmon].[dbo].[c]) AS r3 
              ON r3.pid = r1.patient_id 
WHERE  r3.obx_id = 20937 
       AND Cast(r3.obx_datetime AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() - 1 AS DATE) 
       AND r1.patient_id = 7092425 
       AND obx_value < CASE 
                         WHEN r2.vlag54 = 1 THEN 30 
                         WHEN r2.vlag55 = 1 THEN 50 
                       END 
       AND r2.vlag54 = CASE 
                         WHEN r3.obx_value < 30 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                       END 
       AND r2.vlag55 = CASE 
                         WHEN r3.obx_value BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                       END 
ORDER  BY obx_datetime DESC;
```

The problem is that table C can contain multiple records based on de PID join. This generates the same records because of the multiple records on table C.
The table C needs to e joined as the latest record only so just 1 of C. That way the table A record will not be repeated.

I tried TOP 1 and order by but that can't be used in subquery.

```
-- TABLE A
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A]
    [EVS_MO_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DRUG_ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ATC_CODE] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [DRUG_NAME] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [PATIENT_ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PATIENT_LOCATION] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [MO_DATE] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [MO_START_DATE] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [MO_STOP_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ROUTE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MEDICATION_CONTAINER] [smallint] NULL,
    [PRESCRIBING_DOCTOR_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PRESCRIBING_DOCTOR_SURNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MO_ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MedicationOrders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EVS_MO_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[A]           
     VALUES
           (5411409,'97941689', 'B01AB06','NADROPARINE 0.8ML','7092425','ANBC', '2015-12-15 20:58:06.2030000',
           '2015-12-16 00:00:00.0000000', '', 'IV', 1, 'GEORGE','LAST', 1);
-- TABLE B
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ARTIKELNUMMER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [VLAG54] [bit] NULL,
    [VLAG55] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_VLAG50]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [VLAG100] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ArtikelVlaggen_VLAG100]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[B]
           ([ARTIKELNUMMER]
           ,[VLAG54]
           ,[VLAG55]
           ,[VLAG100])
     VALUES
           ('97941689', 1,0,1);

           -- TABLE C
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[C](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OBX_DATETIME] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [OBX_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OBX_VALUE] [decimal](5, 2) NOT NULL,
    [OBX_UNITS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [REF_RANGE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [FLAG] [varchar](2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[C]
           ([OBX_DATETIME]
           ,[PID]
           ,[DEPARTMENT]
           ,[OBX_ID]
           ,[OBX_VALUE]
           ,[OBX_UNITS]
           ,[REF_RANGE]
           ,[FLAG])
     VALUES
           ('2015-12-15 14:01:00.0000000',7092425, '8NAH', 20937, 27.00, 'mL/min', '> 60', 'L');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[C]
           ([OBX_DATETIME]
           ,[PID]
           ,[DEPARTMENT]
           ,[OBX_ID]
           ,[OBX_VALUE]
           ,[OBX_UNITS]
           ,[REF_RANGE]
           ,[FLAG])
     VALUES
           ('2015-12-15 06:30:00.0000000',7092425, '6ZPA', 20937, 28.00, 'mL/min', '> 60', 'L');
```

Comment: You can use rank or rownumber in the subquery. Also use a online beautifier before posting unformated queries please

Comment: Can you please share your tables' structures? Specifically, what does "the least record" mean? Based on what column?

Comment: Table definitions are big it's difficult to paste all here. Table C has multiple records for the join. I want it to be joined only on the last (newest) record of C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will order them by `OBX_DATETIME` and take only the first one:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pid, obx_id, obx_datetime, obx_value
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY obx_datetime desc)
    FROM   [rxmon].[dbo].[c]
) AS r3 
    ON r3.pid = r1.patient_id and r3.n = 1
...
```

If `OBX_DATETIME` are inserted incrementaly (newer date only), you can order by ID instead.

- This SQL Fiddle with your query and sample data/tables returns 2 rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df36c/2/0
- This SQL Fiddle with the new subquery returns 1 row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df36c/1/0

You are using a LEFT JOIN on r3 but have also have r3 in your WHERE clause with equal operator:

```
WHERE  r3.obx_id = 20937 
    AND Cast(r3.obx_datetime AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() - 1 AS DATE)
```

It will remove NULL value from the left join on r3. Perhaps you should also move it to the sub query or use INNER JOIN.

You should also avoind using the DB name in your query unless this query is run from another DB on the same server. This will be fine:

```
SELECT ... FROM [dbo].[a] AS r1 ...
```

Using `SELECT *` is also a bad habit. You should list only the columns your code will use.

Comment: query doesn't return any results. Also thanks for the advices :)

Comment: with you sample it returns 2 rows with your original query and 1 with my subquery. I added 2 SQL fiddles with your query and the update.

Comment: I had to move OBX_ID=20937 AND CAST(OBX_DATETIME AS date) = CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date) in de subquery then it worked. Very strange that your example works without this modification.

Comment: Add a desc after order by un the subquery. It will change the order

Comment: Thanks Julien it seems to be working have to run it with more records. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

**try this....** @Shift

```
SELECT r1.*, 
       r2.vlag54, 
       r2.vlag55 
FROM   [dbo].[a] AS r1 
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[b] AS r2 
              ON r2.artikelnummer = r1.drug_id 
       LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY id DESC) RN,
               c.*
           FROM C
       ) r3 
              ON r3.pid = r1.patient_id  AND r3.RN = 1
WHERE  r3.obx_id = 20937 
       AND Cast(r3.obx_datetime AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() - 1 AS DATE) 
       AND r1.patient_id = 7092425 
       AND obx_value < CASE 
                         WHEN r2.vlag54 = 1 THEN 30 
                         WHEN r2.vlag55 = 1 THEN 50 
                       END 
       AND r2.vlag54 = CASE 
                         WHEN r3.obx_value < 30 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                       END 
       AND r2.vlag55 = CASE 
                         WHEN r3.obx_value BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                       END 
ORDER  BY obx_datetime DESC;
```

Comment: Also your query doesn't return any results. Strange

Comment: I used your provided data and got one row....which i think is correct.....i can share  the screenshot..... @Shift

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df36c/1

Look  at the sqlfiddle with your provided data... @Shift

Comment: Also Very nice Khaled same as Julien. I will test it with more records but at the moment it seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: isn't ordering the table on ID better than casting the date field and slowing the query for large dataset? @Shift

Comment: Khaled yes indeed ordering by id is cheaper :)